# Force compatibility mode while targeting higher API - Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-youtube-api

I help friend with fixing some bugs in application. Developer that send previous version set `targetSdkViersion` to 23 and Google Developer Console shows error that I cant lower it 19. Problem is, than our app works well with this build configuration without any changes in code:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.swiatkarpia.mobileapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.5"
```

...

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
```

It uses Youtube API and Google Maps API (old versions) and propably this causes the problem.

Is there any way to bypass Google's error?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, once you uploaded a version with taget sdk 23, you will not be able to lower the target sdk in any future versions.

Comment: Is there a "cheat sheet" of things I should change in my app to make it working with targetSdk 23?

Comment: AFAIK, you only have to ask for permissions on startup